# Where is the button-bar border color defined in onsen-ui css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, onsen-ui2, buttonbar

Where is the border color defined in onsen-ui version 2 css?

I'm talking about the widget defined [under the "Segment" section](https://onsen.io/v2/api/css.html#segment-category) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you can add this code in css file:

```
.ons-css .button-bar__button {
  color: rgba(224, 18, 18, 0.77) !important;
  border: 1px solid rgb(224, 85, 18) !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed the border:... rgba... in my css file.

Comment: Before you seen default border color from `onsen-ui`, and now you can set own color from above code like: rgba(224, 85, 18, 0.77), rgb(244, 233, 20), hex color(#000000)